# Arrange a grouped_df by group variable not working

Tags: r, dplyr, grouped-table

I have a data.frame that contains client names, years, and several revenue numbers from each year.

```
df <- data.frame(client = rep(c("Client A","Client B", "Client C"),3), 
                 year = rep(c(2014,2013,2012), each=3), 
                 rev = rep(c(10,20,30),3)
                )
```

I want to end up with a data.frame that aggregates the revenue by client and year. I then want to sort the data.frame by year then by descending revenue.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
        group_by(client, year) %>%
        summarise(tot = sum(rev)) %>%
        arrange(year, desc(tot))
```

However, when using the code above the `arrange()` function doesn't change the order of the grouped data.frame at all.  When I run the below code and coerce to a normal data.frame it works.

```
   library(dplyr)
    df1 <- df %>% 
            group_by(client, year) %>%
            summarise(tot = sum(rev)) %>%
            data.frame() %>%
            arrange(year, desc(tot))
```

Am I missing something or will I need to do this every time when trying to `arrange` a grouped_df by a grouped variable?

R Version: 3.1.1
dplyr package version: 0.3.0.2

**EDIT 11/13/2017:**
As noted by [lucacerone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177738/lucacerone), beginning with dplyr 0.5, arrange once again ignores groups when sorting.  So my original code now works in the way I initially expected it would.

> arrange() once again ignores grouping, reverting back to the behaviour of dplyr 0.3 and earlier. This makes arrange() inconsistent with other dplyr verbs, but I think this behaviour is generally more useful. Regardless, it’s not going to change again, as more changes will just cause more confusion.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try switching the order of your `group_by` statement:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, client) %>%
  summarise(tot = sum(rev)) %>%
  arrange(year, desc(tot))
```

I think `arrange` is ordering within groups; after `summarize`, the last group is dropped, so this means in your first example it's arranging rows within the `client` group. Switching the order to `group_by(year, client)` seems to fix it because the `client` group gets dropped after `summarize`.

Alternatively, there is the `ungroup()` function

```
df %>% 
  group_by(client, year) %>%
  summarise(tot = sum(rev)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(year, desc(tot))
```

---

**Edit, @lucacerone:** since dplyr 0.5 this does not work anymore:

> Breaking changes arrange() once again ignores grouping, reverting back
>   to the behaviour of dplyr 0.3 and earlier. This makes arrange()
>   inconsistent with other dplyr verbs, but I think this behaviour is
>   generally more useful. Regardless, it’s not going to change again, as
>   more changes will just cause more confusion.

Comment: since dplyr 0.5 this does not work anymore: ```Breaking changes
arrange() once again ignores grouping, reverting back to the behaviour of dplyr 0.3 and earlier. This makes arrange() inconsistent with other dplyr verbs, but I think this behaviour is generally more useful. Regardless, it’s not going to change again, as more changes will just cause more confusion.```

Comment: This comment needs to be more visible. Unfortunately the change then change back with the behavior of arrange makes a lot of old, highly upvoted stackoverflow answers incorrect at this stage.

Answer (score 7):

Latest versions of `dplyr` (at least from `dplyr_0.7.4`) allow to `arrange` within groups. You just have so set into the `arrange()` call `.by_group = TRUE`. More information is available [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/arrange)
In your example, try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
        group_by(client, year) %>%
        summarise(tot = sum(rev)) %>%
        arrange(desc(tot), .by_group = TRUE)
```