# arrange() not working on grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume I have the following code. In the last step, where I try arranging it, the code doesn't work and the data frame continues to be arranged in ascending order by `cyl`.

```
library(dplyr)
# create a grouped data frame
df <- group_by(mtcars,cyl)
# rank car from best mpg to worst for every cyl
df <- mutate(df,rank = row_number(mpg)) 
# top 3 best mpg for each cyl
df <- filter(df,rank <= 3) 
# arrange by the number of cyl
df <- arrange(df,desc(cyl), rank)
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not working because you need to `ungroup()` the data before arranging by `cyl`.  The code you are using attempts to order the `cyl` column while it's still grouped by `cyl`. Since those values are all the same (within each group), nothing changes.

To arrange the entire data by `cyl` after ranking, we need to remove the grouping first, and then we can run `arrange()` again.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%                ## group by cylinder
    mutate(rank = row_number(mpg)) %>%   ## rank by mpg
    filter(rank <= 3) %>%                ## top three for each cyl
    arrange(rank) %>%                    ## arrange each group by rank
    ungroup() %>%                        ## remove grouping
    arrange(desc(cyl))                   ## arrange all by cylinder (descending)

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb rank
# 1 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4    1
# 2 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4    2
# 3 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4    3
# 4 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4    1
# 5 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    2
# 6 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4    3
# 7 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2    1
# 8 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1    2
# 9 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    3
```

As a side note, I would recommend that you consider using the `%>%` function for chaining these calls together as it will considerably cut down on assignments made with `<-`.

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555297/dplyr-arrange-a-grouped-df-by-group-variable-not-working